# The opposite category of the category of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

Does anyone know where I can find a description of the opposite category of the category of graphs? The morphisms of the category are graph homomorphisms.

Thank you

Comment: What do you have in mind? «The opposite category of the category of graphs» sounds like a great description of the opposite category of the category of graphs to me :-)

Comment: What kind of description are you looking for? You just gave a very clear description of it.

Comment: I want a category that is equivalent to the dual of the category of graphs. I want the category to be realised, not just an abstract category.

Comment: Since the category of graphs is a concrete one (in the technical sense), its opposite ccategory is concrete (because there is a faithful functor $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}\to\mathsf{Set}$, the powerset functor) This gives a realization of sorts...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the category of graphs is a locally finitely presentable category but not a preorder, so its opposite cannot be locally finitely presentable. This means there is no hope of finding a description of it as a category of algebraic structures of some kind.

Comment: So it's impossible to find such a thing?

Comment: You should make precise what you mean by «such a thing», as otherwise it is impossible to know exactly what you want.

Comment: The discussion on p.11 on graph homs and "opposite graphs" in Wolter's "Category Theory and Diagrammatic Reasoning", 2011: http://www.ii.uib.no/~wolter/teaching/v11-inf223/manuscript.pdf may be of interest.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but *which* category of graphs? Their are several notions of what a graph morphism is.

Answer (score 1):

What about considering a subcategory of the category of graphs and all binary *relations* $R$ between them (such that if edge $e:x-y$ is in relation with $e':x'-y'$ then $xRx'$ and $yRy'$, too)? Specifically, collect those relations $R:G-G'$ which are *inverses* of a graph morphism $f:G'\to G$, i.e. $zRz' \iff z'=f(z)$.